# Syntax error on JQuery for addClass

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.signupbutton').addClass("hidden");

    $('.signupbutton').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this).parent();
        if ($this.hasClass("visible")) {
            $this.removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $this.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I got syntax error on line 3. I don't know where did I do wrong. Is there anything missing here?

I try to make an event where my hidden div will show up when I click on an image (act as button)

But I don't know why I got this error on line 3.

```
<div class="signupbutton">
<img src="Source/Header/images/button2_03.jpg"
    onMouseOver="this.src='Source/Header/images/button2_05.jpg'"
    onMouseOut="this.src='Source/Header/images/button2_03.jpg'" 
    width="128" height="50">
<div>
      <div id="logintable"><table width="240" height="269" border="0">
      <tr>
        <th width="199" height="17" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="10" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="22" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="16" style="font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="53" style="font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><label for="textfield">Username:</label>
          <span style="text-align: left"></span>
          <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="30"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
        </form></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="49"><label for="textfield2">Password:</label>
          <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="30"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="34">Forgot your USERNAME or PASSWORD</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="33"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
          Remember me</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="51"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Sign In" size="20"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
                </table>
    </div>
        </div>
```

here is the html.. i tried to follow one of the method tht i got from the internet but i do change a lil bit. i there anything tht i do wrong?

above is the html

Comment: what does error says ?

Comment: it just say "there is a syntax error on line 3. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error"

im sorry, totally new in jquerry...

Comment: try generating this error in firefox and check what error it prints in console.

Comment: where you get this error in your `ide` or in browser console?

Comment: on my ide. i do try it in firefox but nothing happened actually.

Comment: okay try adding a jQuery library first then above this script. _seemes to me that you are not referencing the jquery library._

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Have you tried to debug this code by adding break points?

Comment: still error and make it worse now the div that i want to hide, not hidden anymore... i didnt touch anything accept for the jquerry and now nothing works... damn this thing hard :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `hide()` and `show()`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.signupbutton').hide();
    $('.signupbutton').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this).parent();
        if ($this.is(":visible")) {
            $this.hide();
        } else {
             $this.show();
        }
    });
});
```

**SEE Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Gn7a/

Comment: Your code also working fine.It added hidden and visible class correctly. You need inspect the output of the fiddle site. See http://jsfiddle.net/2Gn7a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning parent() to the button but you are assigning addClass() to the button so just remove the parent() from that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.signupbutton').addClass("hidden");

    $('.signupbutton').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass("visible")) {
            $this.removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $this.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```